# Multilevel One To Many Relationship using Spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a small demo for meeting room booking.

My entities are City --> Location --> Floor --> Room with one to many relation from top to down.

These are my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="office_city")
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cityId;
private String cityName;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Location> location;

public List<Location> getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(List<Location> location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public int getCityId() {
    return cityId;
}
public void setCityId(int cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
}
public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}
public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[cityId="+cityId+" cityName="+cityName+" location="+location.size()+"]";
}
}

public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int locationId;
private String locationName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cityId")
@JsonBackReference
private City city;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="location",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Floor> floor;


public List<Floor> getFloor() {
    return floor;
}
public void setFloor(List<Floor> floor) {
    this.floor = floor;
}
public City getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(City city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public int getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}
public void setLocationId(int cityId) {
    this.locationId = cityId;
}
public String getLocationName() {
    return locationName;
}
public void setLocationName(String cityName) {
    this.locationName = cityName;
}
}

public class Floor {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int floorId;
private String floorName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="locationId")
@JsonBackReference
private Location location;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="floor",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Room> room;

public List<Room> getRoom() {
    return room;
}
public void setRoom(List<Room> room) {
    this.room = room;
}
public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public int getFloorId() {
    return floorId;
}
public void setFloorId(int cityId) {
    this.floorId = cityId;
}
public String getFloorName() {
    return floorName;
}
public void setFloorName(String cityName) {
    this.floorName = cityName;
}
}
```

But now when I am tring to build I am getting below errors

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Location! Traversed path: City.location.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:337)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:361)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87)
```

Comment: This is the key: `No property id found for type Location` - try naming `locationId` to `id`

Comment: Hi Robert Thanks for quick reply. Where should I be changing locationId to id?

Comment: in your location class - if the error changes to another class, then follow the same pattern

Comment: On further investigation I found the following error too                                     INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: office_room
Jul 19, 2018 6:32:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table office_location add constraint FK_emdg9gon3uwmpdorp1256a7g2 foreign key (locationId) references office_location (locationId)
Jul 19, 2018 6:32:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Error on rename of '.\mrbs@002dauto\#sql-c24_131' to '.\mrbs@002dauto\office_location' (errno: 150)   I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: I noticed that your `Location` and `Floor` classes do not have `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations, thus it is not visible, to which tables they should match. Did you just forget to copy them into your question or are they truly missing?

Comment: Sorry, that is a copy issue. I do have `@Entity` and `@Table` over them. What I am looking for is something like country state city mapping but I don't know how to do that.